# using 'from __future__' with ipython and PYTHONSTARTUP

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I would like to have

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals)
```

loaded in each interactive session, using a `PYTHONSTARTUP` file. This works with basic python (2.7.5, installed with Anaconda), but does not work with ipython (1.0.0, Anaconda). Other `import` statements work with ipython, but `__future__` ones are just ignored (although they work if I enter them on the command line). Is this an ipython bug, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Is this the first (non-comment/docstring) line in your `PYTHONSTARTUP` file? It doesn't seem to be 100% clear whether the code in that file should follow the rules for running scripts, or for typing at the interactive interpreter, so it's conceivable that python might follow one rule but ipython the other…

Comment: It is the first line, yes. It complains if you put it elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two issues here.

---

The first one is more general than `__future__` statements: At least in my tests, ipython 1.0.0 and earlier just don't process the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable at all. You can see this pretty easily:

```
$ echo -e 'print "PYTHONSTARTUP!"\n' > pythonstartup.py
$ PYTHONSTARTUP=./pythonstartup.py ipython
```

Nothing extra gets printed out.

---

[#2706](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2706/) suggested that it should do so, [#3569](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3569) patched it, and 1.1.0 seems to be the first version with the change.

So, the fix is to upgrade to 1.1.0. Or, if you're stuck with an older version, do what was suggested in #2706, and add this to your first `$IPYTHONDIR/profile_default/startup/*py` file:

```
import os

if os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP']:
    execfile(os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP'])
```

---

However, that still won't fix the problem.

The way `$PYTHONSTARTUP` gets run (either explicitly by you or implicitly by iPython) is equivalent to an `exec`. It does explicitly give the appropriate `globals` to the `exec`, which ensures that you end up with the `print_function` tuple available… but that won't affect the parser. (Compare typing `exec('from __future__ import print_function`)` at the interactive shell.)

And the same is true for the startup files described above, the backward-compat `ipython.rc` file (if you have that enabled), and any other files that are supposed to be executed in your interactive environment—they're actually just `exec`'d in your `globals`, which isn't quite the same thing.

Even files executed as part of the `exec_files` mechanism in your `ipython_config.py` or other app-config script are handled this way.

However, lines executed as part of the `exec_lines` mechanism are not. So, that's the solution.

---

Edit or create `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`. (If you're using a different profile, ipythondir, app name, etc., you presumably know that, and know how to adjust.)

If it's not already present, add this line:

```
c = get_config()
```

Then add this:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['from __future__ import print_function']
```

See [Configuring the ipython command line application](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/ipython.html?highlight=exec_lines) for more details.

---

If you really wanted to, you could probably do something like this:

```
import os
try:
    # Make sure to pop it so it won't get exec'd later in the startup
    pythonstartup = os.environ.pop('PYTHONSTARTUP')
    with open(pythonstartup) as f:
        c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines.append(list(f))
except KeyError:
    pass
```

But that seems pretty hacky.

Comment: This isn't true. ipython 1.0.0 was processing `import numpy as np` just fine in the `PYTHONSTARTUP`. And I've just upgraded to ipthon 1.1.0, and it still doesn't process `__future__` statements.

Putting the code you give in an ipython startup file does nothing (although I've verified it's reading the file by putting in a `print` line).

Comment: @user2162806: I just tested with all the versions I have lying around—0.13., 1.0.0, 1.1.0, and 2.0.dev; 0.13 and 1.0.0 don't process `$PYTHONSTARTUP`; 1.1.0 and 2.0.dev do. So that definitely was a problem. There may be an _additional_ problem with `__future__` statements, which I'll look into…

Comment: @user2162806: OK, you're right, a `__future__` statement in `$PYTHONSTARTUP` happens too late. In fact, a `__future__` statement even in `startup/000.py` happens too late. I'll edit the answer with more details, then keep looking…

Comment: Interesting. iPython 1.0.0 as distributed in Anaconda does read `PYTHONSTARTUP` (just verified this). Odd that different distributions of a presumably identical package are different... but thanks for looking into this.

Comment: PS, I was completely wrong about the "too late" bit; it's about whether iPython actually interprets the code as user-typed code or uses an exec-style function as a shortcut, and of all the mechanisms I know about, only `exec_lines` does the former (even though you might think the opposite from the names…).

Comment: Well worked out. ;-) This is actually by design - we felt that executing files shouldn't affect the parser for interactive code (after all, loading the same file by importing it wouldn't), but code specified in `exec_lines` should be able to affect the parser.

Comment: @ThomasK: But if executing the `PYTHONSTARTUP` in the standard interactive interpreter affects interactive code, won't people (like the OP here) expect it to do the same in ipython?

Comment: That's a good point. I think we decided this before we handled PYTHONSTARTUP, and when it was added, it was just added to the list of startup files to execute, without any special treatment. Fun fact, IPython started life as a PYTHONSTARTUP file itself ;-)